# How can I get all the existing shortest paths between two single nodes for graph using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, shortest-path

I know that there are many functions can compute the distance between two nodes, and there are some functions can return the shortest path between two nodes in MATLAB, however, I find all the functions seem only return the first shortest path between two nodes, but I want to find a way to get all the existing shortest paths between two single nodes for graph. For instance, if we have a graph: (1,2), (1,3), (2,4), (3,4), when I query the shortest path between 1 and 4, it should return (1,2,4) and (1,3,4). Thanks!

Comment: I guess that there is no matlab function for that. At a step `random step number` of the dijkstra algorithm, if the algorithm find two equidistants path it choose the first one arbitrary. So at this point the algorithm make a choice. You should create a disjktra algorithm that get back to this step `random step number` after it finish to check if another equidistant path can be found.

Comment: Are the edges weighted or unweighted?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the graph class in MATLAB, which has a shortestpath method which defines exactly the operation you are describing.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.html

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.shortestpath.html

If you are working with a directed graph, same thing applies, but you'd use the digraph class instead.

Or, if you desire the shortest paths between **all nodes** in the graph, the distances method will do that:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.distances.html

Comment: The MATLAB `shortestpath` function returns only a single shortest path. The question is, how do you return *all* of the shortest paths?

Comment: Ah, if that's what is desired, then the `distances` method will do that on the graph class. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.distances.html

Comment: That's not what the question asks, either.

Comment: Is the question asking for ALL possible shorest paths between two nodes S and T? I believe you could obtain this with the ``shortestpathtree`` method. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.shortestpathtree.html#d117e521086. I personally have found the wording of the question a bit confusing to parse for some reason. But, shortest path tree will give you all possible paths between S and T along with a second output, distances. If you are looking to account for possibility of ties in shortest path, that would be one way.